# Autofocus stopped working on Nikon D7200

Tags: autofocus

Autofocus stopped working on Nikon D7200 with Nikon 18-300 lens

Comment: What is your question? Can you provide more details of what might have changed between when it was working and now when it isn't?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photo.SE. Can you please edit your question to provide more information about your problem? Does it not autofocus under _any_ conditions? Is the Focus Mode switch set to A(uto)? What have you done to resolve the problem yourself? Have you researched the problem on other sites? The more information you can provide about what you are (or perhaps, are not) doing, or what has recently changed, the better we can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did my D5500's autofocus stop working?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/73538/why-did-my-d5500s-autofocus-stop-working)

Comment: I'm sure the question is "how can I get it working again?"

Comment: @youcantryreachingme In which case it is still far too unclear from the very limited information provided by the OP how one could get it working again. I mean the answer with an equivalent level of information detail would be: "Fix it."

Answer (score 2):

I'm referring to the below image...

[image: Nikon D7200 with 18-300mm lens]

On the lens barrel, note the sliding switch "M" and "A". "M" means manual focus. Make sure this switch is set to "A".

On the camera body, at the very bottom-right in this image, is a small lever switch. It shows the options "AF" and "M". Set to "AF" for auto-focus.

**Both** the camera body and the lens must be set to auto focus.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely the lens than the camera. Try reattaching the lens and if that doesn't work remove and replace the camera's battery. Nikon has good warranty policies if that doesn't work.